# Mock interface with setting up list of data

Tags: c#, list, moq

```
public interface ICar
{
    public int Id {get;}
    public string Owner {get;} 
{
```

in the test I mock this interface

```
var car = new Mock<ICar>();
car.SetupGet(x=>x.Id).Returns(1);
car.SetupGet(x=>x.Name).Returns("Bob");
```

how can I populate list of mocked

```
var test = new Mock<List<ICar>>().Object.Add(car);
```

this doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please share with us more context? It seems to me that you try to solve the problem from the wrong end. Do you want to mock an interface where you have a method which returns a List<ICar>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"how can I populate list of mocked" as you would populate any other list. But you fill it with mocks

```
var car = new Mock<ICar>();
car.SetupGet(x=>x.Id).Returns(1);
car.SetupGet(x=>x.Name).Returns("Bob");

List<ICar> myList = new List<ICar>();
myList.Add(car.Object);
```

You can do this also in a loop:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    var car = new Mock<ICar>();
    car.SetupGet(x=>x.Id).Returns( i + 1 );
    car.SetupGet(x=>x.Name).Returns($"Bob_{i}");
    myList.Add(car.Object);
}
```